# Is it necessary to stop subscribing in helper level subscriptions with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze

According to [the docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-stop) :

> If you call Meteor.subscribe within a reactive computation, for example using Tracker.autorun, the subscription will automatically be cancelled when the computation is invalidated or stopped;

It is then explicitly mentioned that there is no need to stop subscriptions inside an `autorun`.

Is this also the case for meteor helpers? I believe they count as `reactive computation`, but I'm not entirely sure!

**EDIT**

Here is a snippet of code representing the situation.
The question then goes: Do I need to do something to stop the `objectsSub` or is it all sorted automatically?

```
<template name ="Foo">
 {{#with myContext}}
    {{#each objects}}
     <!--Show stuff-->
    {{/each}}
 {{/with}}
</template>

Template.Foo.onCreated(function(){
  this.subscribe('myContextSub');
});

Template.foo.helpers({
 myContext(){
    return MyContextCollection.findOne();
 },
 objects(){
    Meteor.Subscribe('objectsSub',this.someContextAttribute);
    return ObjectsCollection.find({});
 },
});
```

Comment: Why are you subscribing in a helper? That seems weird to me. Can you show your code?

Comment: I have added a small snippet with the code. The reason I am subscribing in the helper is to have the data context available that I will be able to use in the subscription arguments

Comment: ok, i get what you're doing. i have a couple thoughts that i'll put into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not a fan of doing anything in helpers that has a side effect, such as going to the server. a helper can get called multiple times while the template is active, so imho it should really do nothing more than return a value.

in your case, at a minimum i would tie the subscription to the template, so the subscription goes away when the template is destroyed. e.g.

```
Template.foo.helpers({
 objects() {
    Template.instance().subscribe('objectsSub',this.someContextAttribute);
    return ObjectsCollection.find({});
 },
});
```

more likely, i would handle this "join" on the server side, when the master collection (myContextSub) is published. but that's only if the slave collection (objectsSub) is not expected to be reactive. (in the publish, you can set listeners on the added and changed events and add extra fields to the published objects, i.e. data from objectsSub).

if objectsSub is going to be reactive, then i would probably handle the subscription in onCreated() of the template. on the client, you would set an added listener on the master collection, then subscribe to the relevant slave collection as the items in the master collection are published. the helper could then simply do the find() as it does now. e.g.

```
Template.foo.onCreated(function() {
    let self = this;

    self.subscribe('myContextSub');

    let cursor = MyContextCollection.find();

    cursor.observe({
        added: function(newDocument) {
            // loop through the objects on newDocument, pulling out the context attributes to subscribe one or more times...
            self.subscribe('objectsSub', someContextAttribute[s]);
        },
        changed: function(newDocument, oldDocument) {
            // same as added
        }
    });
});
```

now the slave helper can be simpler:

```
Template.Foo.helpers({
 myContext() {
    return MyContextCollection.findOne();
 },
 objects() {
    return ObjectsCollection.find({});
 },
});
```

in this 2nd example, maybe the thing that's a little odd is i'm using a find() instead the findOne() you're using, in order to access the listeners that way. so perhaps you would need to check the way it's published or filter on the client.

if you wanted to stick with the findOne(), same concept applies: once the data is returned, you could examine it and subscribe to what you needed for the slave collection.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

You are correct that a Template helper is in fact a reactive computation.  Therefore, per the docs, it should follow then that you do not have to stop a subscription started by a helper.  But you know what happens when you assume...

So I decided to test this out to make sure it was actually true in practice.  Based upon my test, the answer to your question is that **you do NOT have to stop a subscription that was started by a helper**.

In case you are curious, here is my testing code (note I used a collection within my app that contains a list of active users).

```
<template name='main_template'>
  <p>Number of Active Users: {{numUsers}}</p>

  {{#if isNotDestroyed}}
    <p>Number of Active Users (from sub-template): {{> sub_template}}</p>
  {{/if}}

  <a href="#" class="js-destroy">Destroy sub-template</a>
</template>

<template name='sub_template'>
  {{numUsers}}
</template>


Template.main_template.onCreated(function() {
  this.destory = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.main_template.helpers({
  numUsers: function() {
    return ActiveUsers.find().count();
  },

  isNotDestroyed: function() {
    return !Template.instance().destory.get();
  }
});

Template.main_template.events({
  'click .js-destroy'(template, instance) {
    console.log('setting destory');
    instance.destory.set(true);
  },
});

Template.sub_template.onCreated(function() {
  console.log("I was created!");
});

Template.sub_template.onDestroyed(function() {
  console.log("I was destroyed!");
});

Template.sub_template.helpers({
  numUsers: function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('activeUsers');
    return ActiveUsers.find().count();
  },
});
```

As you can see, I subscribed to the collection within the sub template, but I am counting the number of records in both the main template and sub template.  On the initial run, both counts return the same value.  However, when I "destroyed" the sub template (achieved by using a ReactiveVar), the count in the main template changed to 0.  This means that the subscription was stopped and the local collection was cleared out.

One final note, I completely agree with what @zim has recommended.  In addition to his suggestions, you could also use the [Meteor Publish Composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) package to handle this in only 1 subscription.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meteor-devtools/ippapidnnboiophakmmhkdlchoccbgje?hl=en) to see when meteor is subscribing and unsubscribing. You will probably see it unsubscribing from your subscription in the helper as @jordanwillis pointed out. Also I recommend this [server transform package](https://github.com/maximummeteor/server-transform) to do everything in one subscription instead of inside a helper.

Comment: that is indeed a useful extension for chrome.